# Set list equal to another reversed list

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listView which contains items, I want to implement filters (name, price, type etc.)

I want to create a "filter list" which is equal to the reverse order of the original list

However when i do this...

```
List<String> itemsList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> filterList = new ArrayList<String>();

filterList = Collections.reverse(itemsList);
```

I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to List"

Comment: show use the declaration of itemlist

Comment: You need to create a copy of `itemsList`, and then reverse the copy. `Collections.reverse` reverses the list in place.

Comment: @Philipp Sander done!

Comment: You are not using Notepad to develop Java code, are you? In that case, I'd say stop, and immediately start using any IDE, having syntax highlight and content assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collections.reverse() manipulates the original list object and returns `void`.

this will do want you want:

```
filterList = new ArrayList<Integer>(itemsList);
Collections.reverse(filterList );
```

Comment: however, if OP really needs two different lists, as per his question title, I'd create a copy of the original list before reversing it.

Comment: @Philipp Sander is copy() actually a method? doesn't show up in the content assist?

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.reverse` reverses list in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Because  reverse method won't return anything back,and you are trying to assign it to some list.

Try

```
Collections.reverse(itemsList);
filterList = itemsList
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the data type of both variables filterList and itemsList match? and does itemsList contain any values? may be its blank